# Placing material ui text field label to left of text field

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to place label of a material ui text field to the left of text field. Like shown here

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-15h58

But this is in the case of FormControlLabel. In my case I need to style the label of the material ui text field. Can someone help me out. I couldn't find anything related to label placement in official documentation below.

https://material-ui.com/api/input-label/

Any pointers would be appreciated! Thanks in advance. Cheers!